# After form submit show / hide div +input field based on checkbox?

Tags: php, jquery

Apparently I am doing something wrong. I have a simple form which reload the page with a bunch of chosen variables (input field values). Now one of my input fields I like to hide and show based on a checkbox. This input field is within a span element, so I just hide/show the span element

I have this part working by

```
 // Show/Hide div span
  $('#showDiv').click(function () {
    $("#element_span_with_input_field").toggle(this.checked);
     if (!$('#element_span_with_input_field').is(":visible")) {
         alert("empty input field");
        $('#inputfield').val('');
      }
 });
```

Now with a simple php $_REQUEST I can check if the checkbox is checked=checked

```
<input <?php if (isset($_REQUEST['showDiv']) && ($_REQUEST['showDiv'] == '1')) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> type="checkbox" value="1" name="showDiv" id="showDiv"  />Show Div
```

and the checkbox works.

Now I thought this should do the trick to set show/hide the div on ready

```
if ($("#showDiv").val() == '1') {
    $('#element_span_with_input_field').show();
    //$('#element_span_with_input_field').css({ visibility: "visible"});//also tried
  } else {
    $('#element_span_with_input_field').hide();
 }
```

My Problem: When I uncheck the showDiv checkbox the div becomes visible when I submit the form (and the showDiv variable isn't even set??)

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console on the browser?

Comment: You want to check for the checked attribute... lemme see, where is that jquery example ... try out `if ($("#showDiv").is(':checked')) {`. I'm a little unclear on your flow, or where the form submits, but I think thats what you were looking for.

Comment: @IncredibleHat it's the unchecking and submitting the form which seems to be my problem. The #element_span_with_input_field is still shown??

Comment: When you submit with a checkbox 'unchecked', it will not show up in the $_POST or $_REQUEST superglobal. Only when they are 'checked' will they submit, and with the value you have set for them. So if you say you are UNchecking the box, and submitting the form... that means it wont have a value, it wont exist, so it thinks the box should be 'open and visible'. If I'm reading your flow right. And since you have `if ($("#showDiv").val() == '1') {` ... it always has that value in the html (thats why you check for `:checked` instead).

Comment: @IncredibleHat, well you are indeed right I. It only has the value of 1 when the checkbox is checked and indeed it won't exist (which i thought is equal to false/0). So can i fix this easily??

Comment: I moved my comments to the answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check during DOM ready if a checkbox is pre-checked or not (based on your PHP setting of the `checked="checked"` attribute), you would look for the `is checked` setting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#showDiv").is(':checked')) {
        $('#element_span_with_input_field').show();
    } else {
        $('#element_span_with_input_field').hide();
    }
});
```

The rest of your code should work out, as you said. Just keep in mind that when a `checkbox` is not checked, there will not be a variable by its name in `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`. So indeed, if it does not exist (or is `empty`), consider it `false`.

As a side note, you may want to tweak the other block a little as such:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showDiv').click(function () {
        $("#element_span_with_input_field").toggle($(this).is(":checked")); // use jquery
        if (!$(this).is(":checked")) { // eval the checkbox state instead
            $('#inputfield').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tx indeed the simple .is(':checked'))  worked ok. Going to incorporate your tweak tommorow in my actual code. I must admit I skip "this" quit often only in a php class.

Comment: Theres a couple 'this' in javascript with jquery. It can be confusing, but normally works out the same. I just try to keep it consistent if I'm within a jquery block or standard. Sometimes 'this' wont work in a callback function though! So you need $(this)